# Ruby Set membership for objects of different types

Tags: ruby, set, typing

Ruby is not a typed language therefore I find this rather queer. Example:

```
class Test
    attr_reader :field

    def initialize(f)
        @field = String(f)
    end

    def ==(other)
        field == String(other)
    end

    def eql?(other)
        field.eql? String(other)
    end

    def hash
        field.hash
    end

    def to_s
        field
    end
end

s = Set.new([Test.new('string')])
# => [#<Test:0x007fc97da17ea0 @field="string">]

puts Test.new('string').eql?(Test.new('string'))
# true

puts Test.new('string').hash == Test.new('string').hash
# true

puts s.member? Test.new('string')
# true

puts s.member? Test.new('other')
# false

puts Test.new('string') == 'string'
# true

puts Test.new('string').eql? 'string'
# true

puts Test.new('string').hash == 'string'.hash
# true
```

But,

```
puts s.member? 'string'
# false
```

Seems like Ruby is enforcing some type checking internally. Is this supposed to be the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main problem is [`String#eql?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-eql-3F):

```
puts Test.new('string').eql? 'string'
# true
puts 'string'.eql? Test.new('string')
# false
```

You're right, there seems to be some internal type checking :

```
rb_str_eql(VALUE str1, VALUE str2)
{
    if (str1 == str2) return Qtrue;
    if (!RB_TYPE_P(str2, T_STRING)) return Qfalse;
    return str_eql(str1, str2);
}
```

Note that your example works when used the other way around :

```
s = Set.new(['string'])
puts s.member? Test.new('string')
# true
```

If you really want to achieve this behaviour, you could monkey-patch `String#eql?`:

```
module TestStringEquality
  def eql?(other)
    other.is_a?(Test) ? other.eql?(self) : super
  end
end

s = Set.new([Test.new('string')])
puts s.member? 'string'
# false

class String
  prepend TestStringEquality
end

puts s.member? 'string'
# true
```

Be careful, this method is probably used in every gem.

Finally, please remember that [`Set`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html) is a pure Ruby implementation with [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Hash.html) as a backend. It might make it easier to google for information and documentation.

Comment: You could add a type check (`other.is_a? Test`) for a less invasive patch.

Comment: I'd probably move the method to a module and either use `refine` or `prepend` to have a proper `super` method. You can then delegate the comparison to `other` (in reverse order) or just call `super`, i.e.: `other.is_a?(Test) ? other.eql?(self) : super`

Comment: Interesting, maybe an optimization in Hash? The core classes can be rather strange if you expect them to behave like ordinary Ruby objects ;-)

Comment: Type coercion would be really nice. Unfortunately, it only exists for numerics in Ruby.